# Binding a function to a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, user-defined-functions

I'd like to bind a MySQL function (UDF) to a column in a table, where the column would act as an alias for the function, and return its value.

A pseudo code example might explain this better than words.

```
TABLE example (
    ...
    col_x => int,
    col_y => int,
    col_sum => function() { return SUM(col_x + col_y}
);
```

What I want to be able to do is:

```
SELECT col_sum FROM example WHERE...;
```

A row where `col_x = 3` and `col_y = 5` should make `SELECT col_sum` return 8.

I know that it's really simple to do this in the query itself, but in this case I'm trying to fix a bug in a project without rewriting lots of existing code.

I'm currently using MySQL 5.5.

(I've tried to google this, but so far I'm just getting results about using UDFs in my queries, which doesn't help.)

Comment: You can't do it the way you want to (a value calculated when you read the column), but you can use a trigger to calculate the value when the row is inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use a view?

```
create view v_table as
    select (colx + coly) as colsum, t.*
    from "table" t;
```

One possibility is to actually rename the original table to something like `_table`, and then create a view with the original table name:

```
rename table "table" to "_table";

create view "table" as
    select (colx + coly) as colsum, t.*
    from "_table" t;
```

Comment: Of course I can use a view, now I feel stupid. :P I was obviously way too focused on the function keyword to be able to use my brain. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add the column and a triggeer to fill the column on insert/update.